# What is the difference between the application/xx and image/xx mimetype

Tags: c#, web, mime-types

Ive seen application/png and image/png mimetypes, whats the difference between these two and why do both mimetypes exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first is an incorrect application of mime type. The correct mime type is image/png. application/png does not exist, and png is only a subtype of image, not of application.

Answer (score 1):

Official MIME type of Portable Network Graphics (PNG) is: `image/png` . Using other MIME type may result in unexpected result, e.g. browser will issue a warning, etc.

Reference: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics)